# How to remove extra trailing zero from SharePoint Look Up field in PowerApps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, powerapp, powerapps-forms

When we edit a row in a SharePoint List which has a PowerApps Form associated with it, the LookUp field displays 10 additional Zero after decimal.

[image]

How to remove that additional 0? I tried finding some properties but I was unable to find.

Answer (score 1):

We could use Text function in Power Apps to convert any value and formats a number or date/time value to a string of text.

However it doesn't work for lookup column.

As a workaround, change the column type of the looked up to single line of text instead of number type.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text

Answer (score 1):

`Abs(ThisItem.DropDown.Selected.Value)` ...Saved my Day
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ABS(ColumnName)
As I have used the following for Label with Text Property
If DropDown.Selected.Value=5 & price Per Unit is 1100 Then via Apply
Abs(ThisItem.DropDown.Selected.Value * ThisItem.Price)
It Gives results: 5500

For further Reference you can Use
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-numericals